# Disapearing image with Picasso

Tags: android, android-fragments, out-of-memory, picasso

In my application I have have a lot of images. In one of fragments (let's name it fragment MasterFragment) I have ViewPager and each page has image and below "page" there is button "Expand" which takes user to different fragment (let's name it DetailFragment) with list, also with images as items.

Images on Master I'm loading with Picasso with this line (because they have match_parent both width and height):

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(filePathFood).into(mImgvFood);
```

Images on Details have height 150dp so i can use fit:

```
 Picasso.with(mContext).load(folderPath + product.getPath()).fit().centerCrop().
        into(viewHolder.mImgvPicture);
```

When user goes back, from Detail to Master fragment, instead of images there are empty places in ViewPager. Sometimes a few (2 from 4) images are loaded.

If I'm not using Picasso my app is constantly throwing Out of Memory exception. Any idea how handle with that?

Comment: Picasso is probably running out of memory. Try using the `resize(int, int)` option in Picasso.

Comment: Try it with placeholder like this `Picasso.with(RegistrationActivity.this).load(mImageCaptureUri).placeholder(place here defaut image).into(viewHolder.mImgvPicture);`